# cmd displays unicode characters as replacements

Tags: windows, cmd, command-line, command-prompt

printing anything non-ascii to either powershell or cmd just shows the replacement character � (though it looks more like [ ] or [?] depending on the font.

[image]

I have tried:

- enabling the "Beta: use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support" checkbox in "Region Settings".

[image]

- using 65001 as my default code page

[image]

I *can* get past this issue using a terminal emulator such as cmder. But is there anything left I can try to fix this for command prompt?

Comment: @Gerhard Yes, my active code page is `65001` even before using `chcp 65001`. `CHCP` displays `Active code page: 65001`.

Comment: “Anything non-ASCII?”  You do need a font that supports the characters  being printed.  Do you have a specific example?

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with the fonts not having specifically monospace character widths. When this is 'solved' using a different terminal emulator, characters that could not be displayed, such as `世界` were not the same width as Latin characters.

Non-ASCII characters could be displayed, just not the ones I was testing, for they were not the right width.

Switching to a font that supports these characters such as "MS Gothic" works.